# How to change the prototype of "animal" and add method "sayName" to print statement

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype

I've been doing a lot of HTML and CSS and now I'm doing a JS tutorial. I ran into this problem though. I don't know how to access the prototype.

Instructions:

> Create a class named Animal with two properties, `name` and `numLegs`. The Animal constructor should have two arguments whose values are assigned to `name` and `numLegs`.
>
> Next, change the prototype of Animal and add a method sayName that prints to the console "Hi my name is `[name]`", where `[name]` is the value of name.
>
> Click "Stuck? Get a hint!" for examples of how to create a class and how to add a method to an object's prototype.
>
> Finally, we have provided the last two lines to test your constructor and `sayName` method. Don't change these!

Here is my code:

```
// create your Animal class here
function Animal(name, numLegs)={
    this.name=name;
    this.numLegs=numLegs;

    this.sayName=function(){
        console.log("Hi, my name is "+this.name);
    }
}


// create the sayName method for Animal

// provided code to test above constructor and method
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```

I get a syntax error. What gives?

Comment: Side note, you didn't follow directions! `sayName` should be added to the prototype, not defined within the constructor.

Comment: Inheritance, constructor functions and prototype are covered in detail here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Comment: Unrelated tip: It might be smart to assign 'this' to a named variable inside the constructor to avoid inheritance issues with `this`. e.g. `var self = this;` at the beginning of the constructor, then use `self` in place of `this` inside of internally defined functions. That way it will always use the constructor scope's `this` instead of the current function's scope `this`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the syntax error is due to the equal sign after your function declaration:

```
function Animal(name, numLegs)=
```

If you remove the equal sign, the function doesn't throw a syntax error anymore (I tried it just now in Chrome's console).

Answer (score 0):

You can check my code and it's working :

```
Animal.prototype.sayName = function(){
    console.log("Hi my name is" + " " + this.name);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create your Animal class here
function Animal(name, numLegs) {
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;

    // create the sayName method for Animal
    Animal.prototype.sayName = function() {
        console.log("Hi my name is " + [this.name]);
    }
};

// provided code to test above constructor and method
var penguin = new Animal("Captain Cook", 2);
penguin.sayName();
```